# Why are we getting a 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_dataset' for Google BigQuery?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

We are attempting to set privileges for our Google BigQuery users.

This code is working when run in a Jupyter notebook - but isn't running in App engine.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials, project=project)
dataset = client.get_dataset(client.dataset(dataset_name))
```

The code gives this error:

> 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_dataset'

We assumed this was because App Engine might be using an older version of BigQuery that doesn't have that method - but when we add the following line...

```
print "Version: ", bigquery.__version__
```

..., the version that is shown is 0.30 which as we understand it should support the get_dataset method.

What are we missing? What could be causing our 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_dataset' error?

---

Addendum: Methods we see from dir(client) are:

```
>  ['SCOPE', '_SET_PROJECT', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__',
> '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__',
> '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
> '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
> '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_connection', '_credentials',
> '_determine_default', '_http', '_http_internal', 'copy_table',
> 'dataset', 'extract_table_to_storage', 'from_service_account_json',
> 'job_from_resource', 'list_datasets', 'list_jobs', 'list_projects',
> 'load_table_from_storage', 'project', 'run_async_query',
> 'run_sync_query']
```

Comment: Which methods does it actually have? You can use `dir(client)` to see them.

Comment: And if you print `client.dataset(dataset_name)`, what is it? I'm wondering if you already have the dataset information, so you don't need to call anything like `client.get_dataset`.

Answer (score 1):

The library is behaving as if it is google-cloud-bigquery<=0.27.0.  You may be able to work with the earlier library methods, e.g.:

v0.30.0:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials, project=project)

dataset = client.get_dataset(client.dataset(dataset_name))

entries = list(dataset.access_entries)
entry = bigquery.AccessEntry(
    role=role,
    entity_type=entity_type,
    entity_id=entity_id)
entries.append(entry)

dataset.access_entries = entries
dataset = client.update_dataset(dataset, ['access_entries'])
```

v0.27.0:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials, project=project)

dataset = client.dataset(dataset_name)
dataset.reload()

entries = list(dataset.access_grants)
entry = bigquery.AccessGrant(
    role=role,
    entity_type=entity_type,
    entity_id=entity_id)
entries.append(entry)

dataset.access_grants = entries
dataset.update()
```